# Does Dialog flow Client require Google sign in?

Tags: python, dialog, dialogflow-es

I am trying to hit dialog flow get request using python client created and passing all the necessary credentials.json file as params. I am not able to hit a sucessful get call in dialog flow. Is there any other way to get the intents from the python client?

Answer (score 1):

For a normal query a sign in from the user is not needed.

Just try this in your console with your API-Key aka your "Client access token".

Insert the Token here and hit this in your console. I got the examplke Command from here: [Dialogflow API query](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query)

Code:

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
"https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query? v=20150910&contexts=shop&lang=en&query=apple&sessionId=12345&timezone=America/New_York"
```

I usually work with POST request as I find them simpler to use.

Now if you want to do APIv2 agent calls like to import an agent or to list all intents, the user will need to authenticate with their Google account each time.

But to answer the question. No for normal requests the user dont have to sign himself in.